# How should I put a command in \circled?

Tags: circles

I want to write a command, for example `\pi` or `\rightarrow`, inside a circle. I tried `\circled{\pi}` but this doesn't work.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 9):

Define `\circled` in your preamble:

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1](char) {#1};}}
```

Use math environment:

```
\circled{$\pi$}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any more information, a possible solution could be:

```
\tikz \node[circle,draw] {$\rightarrow$};
```

Comment: @FarhadRazi The usual way of saying thanks on this site is to upvote the questions that helped you, and to accept the one that helped you the most (if your problem was solved).

Comment: @ hooy, sorry, you are right. but I don't know how to upvote, could you tell me how I do that?

Comment: of course I used @ ignasi's suggestion and that worked. thanks