# \tiny etc. in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I read everywhere that `\tiny`, etc. does not work in mathmode. When I use it in my code, I also get a warning `Command \tiny invalid in math mode`. But in the output it nevertheless works. At least in some places.

I suppose on other machines this will not work, so I would like to not use these commands in math mode. But, all other commands to make small fonts in mathemode do not work as well as `\tiny` does. E.g. in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
$M_{\begin{array}{c}2\\2\end{array}2A}$
$M_{\tiny\begin{array}{c}2\\2\end{array}2A}$
$M_{\scriptsize\begin{array}{c}2\\2\end{array}2A}$
$M_{\scriptstyle\begin{array}{c}2\\2\end{array}2A}$
$M_{\scriptscriptstyle\begin{array}{c}2\\2\end{array}2A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output I want, is the second. I have a subscript consisting of an array, and this array shall have small numbers.
But `\tiny` is the only command which accomplishes that.

Now to my questions:

1. How do I make small subscripts as in the second example without the use of `tiny`.
2. Why does `tiny` work for the array-subscript, but not for the standard subscript.
3. Why does `scriptscriptstyle` work for the standard subscript, but not for the array-subscript.

---

This question is not a duplicate to 
[Size commands do not work in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/size-commands-do-not-work-in-mathmode)
since I am also asking why `tiny` works, although it is written everywhere that it is not working (and furthermore, @egreg said it is no duplicate).

Comment: @DũngVũ `\tiny` is a switch and should not be misused as an environment.

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh sorry I haven't checked :| but sometimes I use `scriptsize` environment successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size commands do not work in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/size-commands-do-not-work-in-mathmode).

Comment: @Johannes_B actually every switch may be used as an environment by design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size commands do not work in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/size-commands-do-not-work-in-mathmode)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Size commands do not work in math mode. However (some) size commands set up math so if you enter a new math expression from text while the size change is in force, you get math of a matching size.  Internally array is an `\halign` in which each cell is surrounded by `$...$` so in fact using `array` is like using `\mbox{empty text $ matrix cell$}` so the entries pick up the size change more or less by accident.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$M_{\begin{smallmatrix}2\\2\end{smallmatrix}2A}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `smallmatrix` always uses `\scriptstyle`

Comment: @egreg, I know, but it's in a subscript so that seems good

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to change the font size in math mode is to put the size-changing command inside a `\mbox`, for example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Or unicode-math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.

\newcommand\mscriptsize[1]{\mbox{\scriptsize\ensuremath{#1}}}
\newcommand\mtiny[1]{\mbox{\tiny\ensuremath{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\( x \mscriptsize{y} \mtiny{\omega} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: x y ω]

You might want only the braces if you need a long expression to wrap.

You can also use `\text` from `amsmath` to insert arbitrary text-mode commands within math mode, such as `\text{\tiny\itshape x}`.

Answer (score 6):

You could define a `tinymatrix` environment modeled on `smallmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% from amsmath.sty, line 960:
\newenvironment{tinymatrix}{\null\,\vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip4\ex@ \lineskip1.2\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil
  $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup\,%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\di}[1]{\begin{tinymatrix}#1\end{tinymatrix}}

\begin{document}

\[
M_{\di{2\\2}2A}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another trick:

```
\begin{equation}
 x = \textrm{\tiny{\(t\)}}
\end{equation}
```

So, here `t` prints small.