# The old issue of overleft/rightarrow revisited, and my own approach

Tags: amsmath, arrows, subscripts, stackengine, overset

I want to try to communicate what I want to achieve with the following code example. I would like to have one left- and right-command for this functionality, which compiles in reasonable time. I am happy with the aesthetics achieved by the routines below. I apologize if that question could be solved using other answers from the site. Thank you for taking a look at it!

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\smash{\mbox{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\overleftarrow{\normalsize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\constantoverrightarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\smash{\mbox{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{\normalsize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\constantfootoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\smash{\mbox{\tiny\ensuremath{\overleftarrow{\footnotesize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\constantfootoverrightarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\smash{\mbox{\tiny\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{\footnotesize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\constantunsmashedoverleftarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\mbox{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\overleftarrow{\normalsize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\constantunsmashedoverrightarrow[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\mbox{\scriptsize\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{\normalsize\hphantom{D}\vphantom{#1}}}}$}{$#1$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}

\begin{document}

I write longer sentences which have inline math and wrap over several lines. It might happen that I speak about a derivative $\constantoverleftarrow{D_{x_1\cdots x_n}}$ and put it inside the text. It is important for me that the arrow of such a formula does not expand over the indices. I used the smashed version of my own arrow here because I do not want that the lines spread apart. 

Of course, it might as well happen that I speak about a derivative
\[
\constantunsmashedoverleftarrow{D_x}
\] 
which occurs in display math. Here, I use the unsmashed version of my own arrow because I want the spacing to be ordinary. This is important, in particular if I have display math with several lines or even boxes around the math from empheq package.\footnote{A derivative $\constantfootoverrightarrow{D_y}$ in a footnote needs to be smaller.} (It might also be important for deliminators. But there, I usually control the size myself and do not use the $\left(\right)$ version. This seems less important to me.)

The experts from \TeX Stackexchange might notice: Such a macro does not always work. Indeed, it will not adjust to subscripts for example, like $\int_{\constantoverrightarrow{D_z}}$. However, I do not need this. I don't have to worry about all the functionality but only about the one I really use.

I finally want to remark: My document may have around 200 to 300 arrows. And using the code above in the preamble takes a lot of time to compile.

\end{document}
```

[Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462947/tiny-etc-in-mathmode), [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248285/arrows-in-superscripts/248297#248297), [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439527/specific-alignment-of-subscripts-in-math-mode-joint-with-overleftarrow-how-to-a).

Comment: I fixed a lot of typos in your code above. Now it compiles.

Comment: You said that *takes a lot of time to compile*. Maybe because the errors I already fixed. Try again with the code above.

Comment: Why don't use simply `\int_{\overrightarrow{D}_z}`?

Comment: @Sigur The point is that the index `$z$` gets shifted to the right. Concerning compiling, I thought it is maybe bad coding.

Comment: Well, it is not clear what is the problem with `z`. It is subscript, so should be moved a little bit. Do you want to reduce the right spacing?

Comment: I added a further link. Take a look at the pdf pictures there. The index in `$D_z$` is at the right place, but in `$\overrightarrow{D}_z$` it gets shifted to the right as an effect of the arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works for me by combining egreg's and Steven's solution. It compiles fast while the above in the question gets timeout. I smash it twice which I forgot in the question. It seems like things get not spread assymetrically at top and bottom now. It is probably not optimal but I can work with it.

```
\newcommand\constantoverrightarrow[1]{\colas#1\endcolas}
\def\colas#1#2\endcolas{\stackengine{0pt}{}{$\smash{\overrightsmallarrow{#1}}$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
  \smash{\phantom{#1}#2}}

\newcommand\constantoverleftarrow[1]{\cola#1\endcola}
\def\cola#1#2\endcola{\stackengine{0pt}{}{$\smash{\overleftsmallarrow{#1}}$}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
  \smash{\phantom{#1}#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overleftsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\leftarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overrightsmallarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrowsmall@\rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand{\overarrowsmall@}[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \ialign{%
      ##\crcr
      #1{\smaller@style{#2}}\crcr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vskip0.4pt}%
      $\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
    }%
  }%
}
\def\smaller@style#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```